# Split a large dataframe into a list of smaller ones based on column names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a large dataframe

```
df <- data.frame( Time = c('2023-07-26 14:30:01', '2023-07-26 15:00:00','2023-07-26 15:30:00', '2023-07-26 16:00:00','2023-07-26 16:30:00'),
                  
                 `[user1] zuzycie` = rnorm(5, 1, 1),
                 `[user1] temp` = rnorm(5, 10, 1),
                 `[user1] level` = rnorm(5, 20, 10),
                 
                 `[user2] zuzycie` = rnorm(5, 1, 1),
                 `[user2] temp` = rnorm(5, 10, 1),
                 `[user2] level` = rnorm(5, 20, 10),
                 
                 `[user3] zuzycie` = rnorm(5, 1, 1),
                 `[user3] temp` = rnorm(5, 10, 1),
                 `[user3] level` = rnorm(5, 20, 10)
                 )
```

Now I would like to split this dataframe into a list of dataframes. The expected list that looks like as follows:

```
> df_list [[1]]
                 Time [user1] zuzycie [user1] temp [user1] level 
1 2023-07-26 14:30:01        1.5365839      9.836822       24.35510
2 2023-07-26 15:00:00        2.6389661      8.206188       30.14941
3 2023-07-26 15:30:00        0.1443759     11.506217       10.23074
4 2023-07-26 16:00:00        1.3582380     11.510744       24.57023
5 2023-07-26 16:30:00        0.5152619     10.362905        9.92493


> df_list [[2]]
                 Time [user2] zuzycie [user2] temp [user1] level 
1 2023-07-26 14:30:01        0.9914846      9.836822       24.35510
2 2023-07-26 15:00:00        0.8715091      8.206188       30.14941
3 2023-07-26 15:30:00        0.3119822     11.506217       10.23074
4 2023-07-26 16:00:00        2.4220240     11.510744       24.57023
5 2023-07-26 16:30:00        1.5912865     10.362905        9.92493
```

I have prepared a solution that divides df with respect to an additional parameter (and not with respect to user)

```
df_lst <- split.default(df, sub('^(X.user)([1-3])(..)*', '', names(df)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do

```r
lapply(1:3, \(x) df[c(1, grep(x, names(df)))])
[[1]]
                 Time [user1] zuzycie [user1] temp [user1] level
1 2023-07-26 14:30:01       0.6251452    10.779584      9.919454
2 2023-07-26 15:00:00       1.3178857    10.713241     38.831825
3 2023-07-26 15:30:00       0.5111944     9.457118     10.710289
4 2023-07-26 16:00:00       3.6586580    10.885778     17.058035
5 2023-07-26 16:30:00       2.6802782     9.651405     13.850497

[[2]]
                 Time [user2] zuzycie [user2] temp [user2] level
1 2023-07-26 14:30:01      0.05292421     8.609834      25.32409
2 2023-07-26 15:00:00      1.59897515     9.929583      19.09544
3 2023-07-26 15:30:00     -0.52361488     9.569120      21.56490
4 2023-07-26 16:00:00      0.79381100     9.407775      12.62688
5 2023-07-26 16:30:00      0.42570459    10.981116      17.98659

[[3]]
                 Time [user3] zuzycie [user3] temp [user3] level
1 2023-07-26 14:30:01       2.1021766    10.960792     15.091672
2 2023-07-26 15:00:00       0.9832517    11.790485      9.542823
3 2023-07-26 15:30:00       1.1617886     8.935835     11.037887
4 2023-07-26 16:00:00       3.0247614    10.017637     32.693872
5 2023-07-26 16:30:00       0.2963057     9.610091     25.938409
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wanted to have a ```Time``` column in each df

Comment: @GrBa ah - see my update

Comment: It does what I wanted. Will you explain to me what ```\(x)``` means. Thank you for taking your time

Comment: @GrBa it is shorthand for `function(x)` since version 4 of R

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, column names like this are cumbersome and are often unnecessary. I think it would be best to extract the user number into its own column and then split by row.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  pivot_longer(-Time, 
               names_to = c("user", ".value"), 
               names_pattern = "\\[(.*)?\\]\\s(.*)$") |>
  group_split(user)

#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   Time                user  zuzycie  temp level
#>   <chr>               <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2023-07-26 14:30:01 user1   2.14  10.5   13.3
#> 2 2023-07-26 15:00:00 user1   1.31  11.2   25.0
#> 3 2023-07-26 15:30:00 user1   2.25  10.5   12.1
#> 4 2023-07-26 16:00:00 user1   0.845  9.39  12.3
#> 5 2023-07-26 16:30:00 user1   0.601  9.35  27.8
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   Time                user  zuzycie  temp level
#>   <chr>               <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2023-07-26 14:30:01 user2  1.20   11.2   10.9
#> 2 2023-07-26 15:00:00 user2  1.78    9.75  14.6
#> 3 2023-07-26 15:30:00 user2  1.37    9.16  34.4
#> 4 2023-07-26 16:00:00 user2  1.22    9.55  27.5
#> 5 2023-07-26 16:30:00 user2 -0.0317 11.8   25.4
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   Time                user  zuzycie  temp level
#>   <chr>               <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2023-07-26 14:30:01 user3  1.44    11.5 17.7 
#> 2 2023-07-26 15:00:00 user3  1.22    12.2  7.66
#> 3 2023-07-26 15:30:00 user3  0.397   10.5 13.1 
#> 4 2023-07-26 16:00:00 user3  0.0922  10.3 18.7 
#> 5 2023-07-26 16:30:00 user3  1.60    11.5 18.5
```